# Expression error for arguments to a function. Only has 2 but says I am passing 3?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, recursive-query, m

I am attempting to call a lot of data from my public API so have created some functions to iterate through to pull the data.  The API doesn't have an offset parameter so can't use that, data has a unique identifier but was taking too long to call using that so am using date ranges to do this. so using fromDate toDate can pull data per month.

I am receiving this error message when executing my query:

Expression.Error: 3 arguments were passed to a function which expects between 1 and 2.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=[List]

The error is pointing to this line: **getDataForDateRange = (start as date, end as date) =>**
So not sure why the error is saying 3 arguments were passed? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
let
// Set the API URL
apiUrl = my_API_URL,

// Set the credentials
user = User,
key = Key,
secret = Secret,

// Set the initial parameters
fromDate = #date(2018, 1, 1),
toDate = #date(2018, 1, 31),
limit = 10000,

// Helper function to retrieve data for a specific date range
getDataForDateRange = (start as date, end as date) =>
    let
        // Convert the dates to the required format (YYYY-MM-DD)
        formattedStartDate = Text.From(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", "en-US"),
        formattedEndDate = Text.From(end, "yyyy-MM-dd", "en-US"),

        // Construct the API URL with the parameters
        url = apiUrl & "?limit=" & Text.From(limit) & "&fromDate=" & formattedStartDate & "&toDate=" & formattedEndDate,

        // Invoke the API and retrieve the data as a list of records
        response = Web.Contents(url, [Headers = [User = user, Key = key, Secret = secret]]),
        data = Json.Document(response, type table [Record = record]),
        records = data[Record]
    in
        records,

// Set the initial result
result = Table.FromRecords({}),

// Loop until there is no more data to retrieve
loop = List.Generate(
    () => fromDate,
    (date) => List.Max(Date.AddDays(getDataForDateRange(date, toDate)[Date], 1)),
    (date) => if date <= toDate then date else null,
    (date) =>
        let
            // Get the data for the current date range
            dateRangeData = getDataForDateRange(date, toDate),

            // Append the current date range's data to the result
            updatedResult = Table.Combine({result, dateRangeData})
        in
            updatedResult
),

// Convert the final result to a table
finalResult = Table.FromRecords(loop)
in
finalResult
```

The API doesn't have an offset parameter so can't use that, data has a unique identifier but was taking too long to call using that so am using date ranges to do this. so using fromDate toDate can pull data per month. This gives a parameter error when trying to run the function compared to when I was just checking the ID.

Comment: Did any of these answers help you? If so please, accept it to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0):

The error at that point means there is an error within the function.

You are using the wrong function to convert date to text string:

Use:  `Date.ToText(end, "yyyy-MM-dd")`

Culture is irrelevant since you are converting a date constant.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to follow, but assuming getDataForDateRange() returns a bunch of dates, then this line does nothing and will error out

```
(date) => List.Max(Date.AddDays(getDataForDateRange(date, toDate)[Date], 1)),
```

potentially you want

```
(date) => Date.AddDays(List.Max(getDataForDateRange(date, toDate)[Date]),1),
```

example of error

```
let  Date =  List.Transform({43835..43870}, each Date.From(_)),
x= List.Max(Date.AddDays(Date, 1))
in x
```